# Google calendar api - can I reuse token form google?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-calendar-api

Can I use token from FE, where user is authorized from Google to insert event into google calendar on backend?
Flow is:

- user uthorized by google on frontend (firebase and google)
- fill form on FE and submit
- on backend side save data into DB and post event on calendar

Can I reuse token from FE? How I can do that?

I try few solutions using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`, and every time I get HTTP 401 or link to authorization in logs...

Currently creation of service looks like:

```
    protected void initialize() {
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = createClientSecrets();
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = createGoogleAuthorizationCode(clientSecrets);
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = createReceiver();
    Credential credential = createCredentials(flow, receiver); // here I get link to authorization in google :(
    credential.setAccessToken(getAccessToken());
    service = createCalendarClientService(credential);
}

private GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow createGoogleAuthorizationCode(GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets) {
    try {
        return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory())
                .setAccessType("online")
                .build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private LocalServerReceiver createReceiver() {
    return new LocalServerReceiver.Builder()
            .setPort(port)
            .build();
}

private Credential createCredentials(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow, LocalServerReceiver receiver) {
    try {
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver)
                .authorize("user");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private Calendar createCalendarClientService(Credential credential) {
    return new Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: You need an access token which was authorized with the proper scope for use with Google calendar.  Which scope will depend upon which endpoint you are trying to use.  Have you checked the sample? https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/java

Comment: Hi OP, can you clarify what FE is? I'm quite unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: @NaziA i would assume they mean FrontEnd

Comment: yes, I mean FrontEnd. I tried use as QuickStart on google calendar documentation, but I got link with uthorization when I create `Credential`: `new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver)`. It's before I set access token. I think I should use token in constructor or when I create `AuthorizationCodeFlow` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've found out how to do.
First. Authorization with access token should be on front-end. I use angular and firebase for uthorization.

- install `gapi` and `gapi.auth2`
- create on google (https://console.cloud.google.com) app and authorization data for web client (OAuth 2.0)
- then I authorize user in google

as below:

```
private async loginWithGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    await this.initializeGoogleApi();
    const googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    if (!this.isLoggedWithGoogle()) {
      const googleUser = await googleAuth.signIn();
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN, googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
      sessionStorage.setItem(this.GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN, googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token);
    }
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(this.googleToken);
    await this.angularFireAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }

  private isLoggedWithGoogle(): boolean {
    return !!sessionStorage.getItem(this.GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN);
  }

  private async initializeGoogleApi(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      gapi.load('client', () => {
        gapi.client.init(environment.calendarConfig);
        gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', () => {
          resolve();
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

now I send acces token with header to back-end and there  I can insert event on google or do whatever I want.

```
public String insertEvent(Event event, String accessToken) {
    try {
        initialize(accessToken);
        return service.events()
                .insert(CALENDAR_ID, event)
                .execute()
                .getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void initialize(String accessToken) {
    Credential credential = createCredentials(accessToken);
    service = createCalendarClientService(credential);
}

private Credential createCredentials(String accessToken) {
    return new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
}
```